# For an object in circular motion, does speed affect the amplitude of sound it creates?

Tags: kinematics, acoustics

First of all, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question and I've missed something obvious. I used to have an instrument that was a small drum tied to a piece of wood. When you hold the wood and swing the drum around (in circular motion) it creates a sound. The faster I swung , the louder the sound was. Is this because of an increase in speed?

Edit: image of the instrument

[image]

Comment: "An object in circular motion" does not, by itself, generate sound. You'll have to be more specific about what exactly the instrument was, the sound is likely generated by air passing over its surface/through a cavity in a specific manner.

Comment: And/Or could you please specify the name of the instrument? It would help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've added an image to the original post. It's called an Indonesian bullroarer. The vibrations are created by the nylon string rubbing against the wood as it spins, which is amplified by the drum at the end of it.

Comment: @AmolSharma OK, so it's "bullroarer" but instead of spinning airfol it has a drum to amplify the string vibrations?

Comment: Yes. Ah I think I see now. Is it simply that increased speed means greater kinetic energy in the string (since $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, which through the drum would result in a greater amplitude?

Answer (score -1):

The increase in speed results in increase in pressure of string against the stick because of greater centripetal force, which in turn increases the volume of the sound of friction of string against stick.